# Upgrade problem with content dabatase

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade

Have you seen an instance where the stsadm preupgradecheck passed on Features, but the Test-SPContentDatabase found errors and the mount failed?

Comment: If you can copy & paste the error log here we might be able to shed some light

Answer (score 1):

There were multiple versions of the pre-upgrade checker.  It first arrived in SP2, but was updated with the Oct 2009 updates.

Overall though I've always found that the Test-SPContentDatabase is the most accurate, and if it identifies problems then you will have issues completing the upgrade.  Resolve those issues and then proceed with mounting the content database.